# Async await JS not assigning values correctly

Tags: javascript, async-await

The following returns initValue.xx undefined, why so? Is this not the correct way to use async await?

```
const initVal = await this.call(this.fetchUrl, null, 'GET')
const db = await initVal.data.variables[1].values[1]
const vy = await initVal.data.variables[2].values
const re = await initVal.data.variables[0].values
```

this.call -

```
async call(url, query, method) {
try {
      const res = await fetch(url, { method, data: query })
      const json = await res.json()
      return json
    }
    catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
}
```

If I console.log(initVal) I get the correct values, why not in the variables? I have wrapped the function in async containing the variables.

the output of `initVal`:

```
[ { code: 'Region', text: 'region', values: [Array], valueTexts: [Array], elimination: true }, { code: 'ContentsCode', text: 'tabellinnehåll', values: [Array], valueTexts: [Array] }, { code: 'Tid', text: 'valår', values: [Array], valueTexts: [Array], time: true } ] }
```

Comment: can you post the print of `console.log(initVal)`?

Comment: because your function `call` must return a promise. Also, call is a function in javascript, you should rename it with a descriptive name.

Comment: Not the reason for your problem, but `const db = await initVal` the await here is not doing anything, initVal has already been resolved, unless of course `values[1]` happens to be a promise, but I doubt it.

Comment: Sure, it prints this:

`[ { code: 'Region',
       text: 'region',
       values: [Array],
       valueTexts: [Array],
       elimination: true },
     { code: 'ContentsCode',
       text: 'tabellinnehåll',
       values: [Array],
       valueTexts: [Array] },
     { code: 'Tid',
       text: 'valår',
       values: [Array],
       valueTexts: [Array],
       time: true } ] }`

Comment: If you don't intend on handling an error in `call`, don't use `try`/`catch`, instead `return res.json()` - the error will automatically bubble up because that's how promises were designed to work.

Comment: @dun32  `because your function call must return a promise. `   It most certainly does..

Comment: `initVal.data.variables[1].values[1]` doesn't line up with what you have just posted.   Maybe `initVal[1].values[1]` would fit.

Comment: there is not attribute `data` inside `initVal` due to it is an array of objects

Comment: Also after you `await` the `call()` there is no need to `await` individual properties on the object you've already received.

Comment: @Kieth there's no need to return a promise as the function is already declared async and is implicitly wrapped in a promise.